# cut command issue with 2nd column

Tags: shell, unix, cut

I m trying to cut certain valures from string. Its working as expected for the first column but when I m trying for second column its not giving desired output.

Code and output

```
[psatav]$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | cut -d'|' -f1
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1='2016-04-16 00:00:00'
[psatav]$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | cut -d'|' -f2
 '2016-04-16 20:00:00'
```

Second command should return :-

```
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2='2016-04-16 20:00:00'
```

Comment: nopes, it shouldn't

Comment: @dnit13 :- What I m missing ? how come its working fine for 1st column and not for the 2nd. I have mentioned desired output. What changes I need to make in the command then ?

Comment: @PravinSatav: The `-f1` and `-f2` works this way, as soon as the de-limiter is met, it prints the value exactly before and after it. so the pattern `$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2=` is lost when using `-f2` because only `'2016-04-16 20:00:00'` is a part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is passing `$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1='2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'` this whole string to cut so for f1 it cuts

```
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1='2016-04-16 00:00:00'
```

and for f2 it cuts only `'2016-04-16 20:00:00'`

If you don't want to use awk and stick to cut here is what you should do

```
echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2'=$(echo "'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | cut -d'|' -f2)
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2= '2016-04-16 20:00:00'

echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2'=$(echo "'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | cut -d'|' -f1)
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME2='2016-04-16 00:00:00'
```

Comment: ^ Nice way of doing it too!

Comment: Its working for me. and also got what was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

The `cut` command in your OP will not work that way, you can use `awk` with [`multiple delimiters`](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/07/awk-10-examples-to-read-files-with.html) like this way:-

```
awk -F'[=|]' '{gsub(/ /, "", $2); printf "%s=%s\n", $1, $2}'
awk -F'[=|]' '{gsub(/ /, "", $3); printf "%s=%s\n", $1, $3}'
```

For your case,

```
$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | awk -F'[=|]' '{ gsub(/ /, "", $2);printf "%s=%s\n", $1, $2 }'
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1='2016-04-16 00:00:00'

$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | awk -F'[=|]' '{ gsub(/ /, "", $3);printf "%s=%s\n", $1, $3 }'
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1='2016-04-16 20:00:00'
```

White-spaces are removed using `gsub` on each field before passing it to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting delimiter for `cut` as `|` and hence `-f1` cuts everything before first `|` and prints the required output.

But `-f2` will cut the data between first and second `|` which is what you are getting.

You can use below `awk` commands to get your required output:

```
bash-4.1$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | awk -F"=" '{
split($2,a,"|"); print $1,"=",a[1]}'
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1 = '2016-04-16 00:00:00' 
bash-4.1$ echo '$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1'="'2016-04-16 00:00:00' | '2016-04-16 20:00:00'| '2016-04-17 08:00:00'" | awk -F"=" '{
split($2,a,"|"); print $1,"=",a[2]}'
$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1 =  '2016-04-16 20:00:00'
```

- `-F"="` argument sets delimiter to `=` and hence `$1` will contain
  `$$JOB_ESTD_TIME1`.
- `split` function splits `$2` (which is rest of
  the data after `=`) and stores it in array `a`.
- `print` prints the
  required fields from array.